# Write a users news feed with the facebook api

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How would you use the facebook api to get a user to login with the facebook login button and then use the api to get that user's news feed and write it out on the same page

Comment: Which specific part of this are you looking for help with?  The whole thing?  If so, I'd break it down into separate questions (how do I let a user to log into my application with facebook?, how do i get a user's news feed?, how do I parse a user's news feed?).  All three have probably been individually answered here...

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use Graph API Explorer, it solves these issues 9 times out of 10, until you're stuck with using FQL. You can access this via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

To answer your question, you can get the user's news feed by hitting.

https://graph.facebook.com/userid/home?access_token={access_token} to pull in a user's friend's updates. Note that this requires the extended permission of "read_stream".

To get a user's own status updates, change it to /status?access_token={access_token} - this requires the permission of "user_status".

Parsing it to write it out is a different Q&A altogether. You'll want to look up JSON or XML parsing depending on your setup.